# Drilldown on column graph using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, drilldown

I need to create a drilldown on the type of column graph shown below. This is what I have done so far. I am able to create the simple graph but not sure how to implement the dropdown functionality. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Please note that the sample data given comes from a python script.

[image: Sample column graph]

```
function create_graph() {

var maingraph = {{ maingraph|safe }}
chart = new Highcharts.Chart ({
    chart: {
         height: 600,
         width: 1200,
         renderTo: container1,
         type: 'column'
         //reflow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: maingraph[0].graphTitle
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: maingraph[0].xAxisLabels
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: maingraph[0].yAxisTitle
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: generateMainData({{ maingraph|safe }}),
    <!--drilldown: {
        <!--series: generateChildData({{ childgraph|safe }})
    <!--}
 });
}

function generateMainData(g) {
    return [{ name: 'Males',
              data: g[0].yAxisValues
              <!--drilldown: what to write here?
    }, {
        name: 'Females',
        data: g[1].yAxisValues }];
        <!--drilldown: what to write here?
}

if ({{ maingraph|safe }}) {
    create_graph();
}

</script>

maingraph = [{'xAxisLabels': ['Trait1', 'Trait2'], 'yAxisTitle': 'yTitle', 'graphTitle': 'Title', 'xAxisTitle': 'Traits', 'yAxisValues': [0.41, 0.71]}, {'xAxisLabels': ['Trait1', 'Trait2'], 'yAxisTitle': 'yTitle', 'graphTitle': 'Title', 'xAxisTitle': 'Traits', 'yAxisValues': [0.28, 0.27]}]

childgraph = [{'Trait1': {'xAxisLabels': ['Facet1', 'Facet2'], 'yAxisTitle': 'yTitle', 'graphTitle': 'Title', 'xAxisTitle': 'Facets', 'yAxisValues': [0.19, 0.17]}, 'Trait2': {'xAxisLabels': ['Facet3', 'Facet4'], 'yAxisTitle': 'yTitle', 'graphTitle': 'Facets', 'xAxisTitle': 'Facets', 'yAxisValues': [0.96, 0.22]}}, {'Trait1': {'xAxisLabels': ['Facet1', 'Facet2'], 'yAxisTitle': 'yTitle', 'graphTitle': 'Facets', 'xAxisTitle': 'Facets', 'yAxisValues': [0.33, 0.34]}, 'Trait2': {'xAxisLabels': ['Facet3', 'Facet4'], 'yAxisTitle': 'yTitle', 'graphTitle': 'Facets', 'xAxisTitle': 'Facets', 'yAxisValues': [0.12, 0.42]}}]
```

What I want is that when I click on the Trait1 column in the main graph, I should get the two columns Facet1 and Facet2. The difficulty is how to make the script differentiate between the column for male and female for the same trait.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, see [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown) link to know how drilldown should be implemented. There is a fiddle link below, you can see it for your reference. In this case for the respective bars, you have give the drilldown value. Then in the drilldown key, you can provide the data for the graph that you need to show on that drilldown. Here is the sample code

```
series: [{
        name: 'Total count',
        color: colors[3],
        data: [{y: first_data[0], drilldown: 'first_drilldown', name: 'first', color: colors[3], display_name: 'First'},
          {y: second_data[0], drilldown: 'second_drilldown', name: 'Second', color: colors[3], display_name: 'Second'}]
      }],
  drilldown: {
        series: [{
          id: 'first_drilldown',
          name: 'fd',
          data: first_data[2]
        },{
          id: 'second_drilldown',
          name: 'sd',
          data: second_data[1]
        }]
```

As you can see, you provide `drilldown: 'first_drilldown'` to show which drilldown should it show.

Comment: This sample gives you an idea how to handle the drilldown if you want need to load some data via ajax: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/async/

Comment: What do you mean by ajax? I am able to perform drilldown without making any ajax calls. I am setting the data in the js variables when the page loads and then using that data to generate graphs. There is not ajax call involved

Comment: Oh..the fiddle uses ajax. But still if you load all your data initially, you can use the same in generating graphs. Please see the code sample that I had provided in the answer

Comment: I just wanted to provide a sample where you can see how it can be hanlded if you need to load your drilldown data from a server (and don't have all the data initally)

Comment: @geeky_sh: I understand how to implement drlldown, my question is how to do it using my two data structures `maingraph` and `childgraph`. It woud be nice if you could give an example using my sample code as reference.